# Powershell: Assign array value to dynamic variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch the IP address of the machine.

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('testpc') | Select-Object -expand IPAddressToString
```

and it is returning the IPAddress but this machine has more than one network adaptor.
So, it is returning 3 IP addresses.

```
10.4.6.10
192.168.100.8
::1
```

I need an IP address in a separate variable.

Any advise how can i assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Select-Object` will return an array, if it returns more than one object, you can access each element by an index for example:

```bsh
([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('testpc') | Select-Object -expand IPAddressToString)[1]
```

Output:

> ```
> 192.168.100.8
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can i assign other IP address to variable. Because it may vary system to system.

Comment: What may vary? The IP addresses on each system (sure) or the number of IP addresses on each system?